# Проблема с вычислением ширины элемента

Tags: html, css

Прохожу JavaScript'ом по HTML-коду и вместо атрибутов `title` после тегов ставлю `span`'ы с классом `tooltip` и текстом подсказки. Проблема в том, что есть некоторые пункты меню, выводимые в виде значков с заданной шириной и такой структурой:

```
<li {ширина задана в css}>
    <a... title = "..."></a>
    <span class = "tooltip">...</span>
</li>
```

В результате тег `span` имеет ширину, равную ширине слова максимальной длины в подсказке, то есть, подсказка выводится по 1 слову на строку. Можно как-то решить эту проблему с помощью css? У класса `tooltip` задано свойство `max-width: 300px` - необходимо, чтобы в любом случае, независимо от того, где находится этот `span`, его размер автоматически растягивался до этого значения.

http://jsfiddle.net/kjfbym32/

Answer (score 1):

давайте попробуем следующее: 
`white-space: nowrap`

Comment: Так текст вообще не будет переноситься. Нужно, чтобы при достижении `max-width` текст переносился на следующую строку.

Comment: если честно, ерундой вы какой-то занимаетесь. посмотрите как сделаны другие плагины такого типа - наверное не зря они ТАК сделаны? и проходить по всем элементам, ища `title` и вставляя в `DOM` блоки - ОЧЕНЬ дорогая операция.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это свойство вам поможет:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Я прикрепил ссылку на пример снизу. Указанное свойство не решает проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте тултипу `width: 300px`, если нужно, чтобы тултипы были всегда одного размера

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Такой ответ тоже имеет право на жизнь. Хотя свой -1 он и заслуживает, это всё же ответ.